# Can i change parameters with vue router without cause a reload of the page?

Tags: vue.js, router

i tried to change the parameters of the url of my application but i want to do it silently without refreshing the page. i tried to use the replace function of router and router.push({replace:true}), but it behaves the same as router.push.
any ideas?

router.replace
router.push({replace:true})

Comment: Hi! Please [read the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) first. Have you checked the documentation? I think this [Vue Router guide](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/) tells you to push routes like `this.$router.push('/login')` - what are your routes? What is the route you're trying to push? You don't have to replace, what was the reason for that? Vue routes can have parameters, check [Vue Router parameters documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html).